# Strange UIScrollView and NavigationController Problem

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiview

I've run into a strange problem, i have few uiviewcontrollers which i'm managing via navigationcontroller, each uiviewcontroller contains a uiscrollview with content in it.
Now, i push a viewcontroller into a navigation controller, say, Screen A, the uiscrollview does not scroll/bounce, A button on the scrollview of Screen A pushes Screen B to the controller, and user pops back to screen A, the scrollview bounces!

Not sure why are my uiscrollviews are not able to bounce for the first time they are displayed, any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. Defined outlet in the code and set scrollview bounces property to true, and it works.
Same property is however defined in the nib, still wondering why it didn't work on first load only.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `-(BOOL)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` method in the scrollview or where it is called in the parent view, is the delegate for the scrollview being properly assigned if so throw some logs in the `- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` and see what gets thrown back.

Also check where you are setting the content size for the scrollView, if at any stage the content size is less than the visible area, it wont scroll.

Comment: I have added the scrollview from the interface builder, just for the sake of 'bounce' effect, what then?

Comment: Are you linking it back to your code and calling [_scrollView setContentsize:CGSizeMake(x,y)] ? Is the parent view implementing the UIScrollViewDelegate and have you linked that back to the interface builder?

Comment: No, all i have done is put it in the interface builder, no code connections to it, and it works on the second time view is displayed, i am wondering whats wrong for it in bouncing on the first load.

Comment: You'll need to hook it up if you want to debug the problem.